# Image and "painted component" dissapears when exporting to executable JAR file FIXED

Tags: java, eclipse, image, executable-jar, paintcomponent

My problem is that when I run my program in Eclipse it works completely fine. Everything works as it should but when I export it as an and try to run the file it doesn't. From the beginning I imported an image this way:

```
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\graphics\\raceTrack3.PNG"));
} catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("MAP NOT FOUND.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//@Overide
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    //....drew more stuff using g.draw...
```

When I tried to run this as a JAR-file it painted everything but the image, the "logic" also worked perfectly. So I searched around and everywhere I looked people said do it this way instead:

```
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/raceTrack3.PNG"));
} catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("MAP NOT FOUND.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

(Yes, I have created a new source Folder for the project and in that source folder I have a folder called images).

So I did this and everything still workes fine when I run it from Eclipse. However, when I export this and try to run the JAR-file now nothing shows up. It opens a window but nothing painted inside it. Just a tiny tiny window with the minimize, maximize and close buttons. Does anyone have a clue about what I am doing wrong? I can upload code but I don't really know what parts are of interest...

I solved it by replacing .PNG with .png
Gj me..

Comment: Like every other question on this subject `src` won't exist at runtime and you should never reference it it in any path you use. Also, the image will not be a `File` once the program is compiled and packaged as a Jar, it becomes an embedded resource (a series of compressed bytes in a zip file) which can no longer be referenced as a file, instead, you should be using `Class#getResource`, for example `getClass().getResource("/graphics/raceTrack3.PNG")`

Comment: I don't think I do reference to the src. I have created a new source folder, se picture: http://i.imgur.com/3yL1oHR.png.

Is there anything I have missed? :s

Comment: Okey, I'm an idiot, I changed .PNG to .png and that solved it... Thanks for helping!